# To open nodes first before checking the nodes in Jstree - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

```
for (var j = 0; j < eles.length; j++) {

    if (eles[j].trim().length != 0) {

        jQV6('#jstreeDivforBrowse').jstree("open_node", "#" + eles[j]);
        jQV6('#jstreeDivforBrowse').jstree("check_node", "#" + eles[j]);

        //Tried the below too

        /*
        var tree = jQuery.jstree._focused();
        tree.open_node("#"+eles[j], function () {
        tree.check_node("#"+eles[j], true, null); });
        */
    }
}
```

The array `eles[]` has a list of ids which needs to be opened first before it is getting checked.

What happens when I run the above code is, the nodes are getting checked even before the child nodes are expanded.

Is there anyway in jstree to wait for the completion of expansion of child nodes before we execute the other steps like checking the nodes, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQV6('#jstreeDivforBrowse').jstree('open_node', "#"+eles[j], function(e, data) {
    jQV6('#jstreeDivforBrowse').jstree('select_node', "#"+eles[j]);
}, true);
```

Possible Duplicate of [JsTree Open a node then select a child node (using json_result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307004/jstree-open-a-node-then-select-a-child-node-using-json-result)

Comment: I had tried this just sometime before. The nodes are getting opened the but not getting checked.